# Open graph og:image

Tags: html, facebook-opengraph

I use open graph on my website in views index.php, about.php, contact.php:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://website.com/img/blog/open-graph.png">
```

But `og:image` work only if url is `https://website.com/index` or `https://website.com/about` or `https://website.com/contact`.

And if url is `https://website.com` or `https://website.com/` it doesn't work.

I can not understand what it is connected with.

Comment: "it does not work" is not enough for us to help you, i´m afraid. we obviously need more information. what does the debugger say?

Comment: by "url" do you mean the URL of the page you are on or the URL specified in the `meta`  link? Is the image accessible? How do you know it doesn't work?